# Pandas groupby with capture groups from extractall

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with Pandas `extract()` method to feed the capture group into `groupby`. A small example of the result of this process is something like the one illustrated below:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from io import StringIO

DATA = StringIO('''
colA;colB;colC
Foo;1;1
Bar;2;2
Foo,Bar;3;3
''')
df = pd.read_csv(DATA, sep=';')

m1 = df['colA'].str.extract('(Bar|Foo)', flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)

for t, _d in df.groupby(m1):
    t
    _d

# 'Bar'
#   colA  colB  colC
# 1  Bar     2     2
#
# 'Foo'
#       colA  colB  colC
# 0      Foo     1     1
# 2  Foo,Bar     3     3
```

However, the row with index `2` (third row) is only captured in the `Foo` group, whereas I wanted to capture it in both `Foo` and `Bar`.

Playing around with the `extractall()` method seems to capture all matched groups, but apparently cannot be used together with `groupby()` because pandas complaints about the grouper not being 1-dimensional: `ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional`

```
m2 = df['colA'].str.extractall('(Bar|Foo)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

#            0
#   match
# 0 0      Foo
# 1 0      Bar
# 2 0      Foo
#   1      Bar
```

The desired output for `groupby()` would be something like the following:

```
for t, _d in df.groupby(somematch):
    t
    _d

# 'Bar'
#       colA  colB  colC
# 1      Bar     2     2
# 2  Foo,Bar     3     3
#
# 'Foo'
#       colA  colB  colC
# 0      Foo     1     1
# 2  Foo,Bar     3     3
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` is designed so that each row belongs to exactly one group, which is not true in your use-case. You'd need to extract the rows manually. One way to do so:

```
words = ['Foo','Bar']
for word in words:
    print(df.loc[df['colA'].str.contains(word)])
```

Output:

```
      colA  colB  colC
0      Foo     1     1
2  Foo,Bar     3     3
      colA  colB  colC
1      Bar     2     2
2  Foo,Bar     3     3
```

Or, if your data is given as in the example, you can use `get_dummies` to split the keywords within each cell:

```
keys = df['colA'].str.lower().str.get_dummies(',')
for key,data in keys.items():
    print(df.loc[data.eq(1)])
```

Comment: Thanks! In this particular case, I cannot use your second suggestion because `colA` includes more complex text, but is nice to know about the `get_dummies` alternative too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) before the `groupby`:

```
m = (df['colA'].str.extractall('(Bar|Foo)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
     .droplevel('match')
    )

for key, group in df.reindex(m.index).groupby(m):
    print(key)
    print(group)
```

Output:

```
Bar
      colA  colB  colC
1      Bar     2     2
2  Foo,Bar     3     3
Foo
      colA  colB  colC
0      Foo     1     1
2  Foo,Bar     3     3
```

Comment: Just a minor correction for consistency: it should be `df.reindex(m.index).groupby(m)`.